# Can we make the different transformation functions for the Spark Streaming running on different servers?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))
```

For the above example, we know there are two transformation functions. Both of them must running at the same process\server, however I want to make the second transformation running on a different server from the first one to achieve scalability, is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you let spark deal with scalability? That's its whole purpose...

Comment: As maybe some transformations very heavily , so I need to isolate them from the other transformations. Anyway if I need this requirement , is it possible ? Such as transfer the results of the first transformations to another server, and another server continue do the transformation on it with a smoothly way.

Comment: The whole point of using frameworks like Spark is to avoid dealing with low level details. Also Spark is one of the most scalable platform which exist. And unless you are a "master" of distributed system, you will struggle to come up with a more scalable application than the one merely using Spark.

Comment: Two transformations related to two Jobs, I have no idea two jobs must running in the same server , or maybe running in the different servers  automatically if the spark think it is necessary to.

Comment: Your two examples are running in a sequence, lines -> words -> pairs, in this case spark would distribute the task between all resources, the only overlap might be just before `words` finished processing and `pairs` started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear things up: a Spark transformation is not an actual execution. Transformations in Spark are lazy which means nothing gets executed until you call an action (e.g. `save`, `collect`). An action is a job in Spark.

So based on the above, you can control jobs but you cannot control transformations. A Spark's job will be distributed on multiple executors by splitting the processed data (RDD) among them. Each executor will apply the job (multiple transformations) on its split and then the results will be collected again. This will significantly reduce network usage.

If you can perform what your asking about, then the intermediate results (which you actually don't care about) should be transformed over the network which in turns will add a great network overhead.

Comment: For normally spark batch job it will be distributed on multiple executors, however you are sure the job for the spark streaming micro-batch  also be will be distributed on multiple executors ?

Comment: From Spark Streaming Programming Guide [https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-programming-guide.html]: "Internally, it works as follows. Spark Streaming receives live input data streams and divides the data into batches, which are then processed by the Spark engine to generate the final stream of results in batches." So basically there is no difference.